# How do i return JSON results from BING Search Engine API

Tags: bing, bing-api

At the moment i am only able to do my searches based on logging in to datamarket azure.

Results returned are formatted in a table form and i dont fidn any way to return them in JSON format.

A link is displayed after results are returned but when that link is pasted in the URL section of a browser it requires a username and a password.

Example of returned URL
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27car%27

There used to be an api Using REST for it but now it only return errors and is no longer working.

Is there any way to use this BING API and retrieve it's return queries?

Returned Error after failing to attempt to log in to azure 
The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove the `v1` from your URL, and add `$format=json` to the end of your query, as detailed in the [schema guide](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!109&app=Word&authkey=!ACvyZ_MNtngQyCU):

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27Xbox%27&$format=json
```

To get the link to work, you need to provide it your hashed credentials, to get that, follow these steps:

1. Login to the Azure Marketplace.
2. Browse to the [search api listing](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=309650)
3. Click on the "Explore this Dataset" link (its only visible if you are logged in).
4. Once it opens, on the top click on "Show" next to "Primary Account Key"
   [image]
5. Save this hashed value and use it in your code as the authentication digest.

Comment: it still requires a log in from me which when i have inputted my hotmail account it doesnt work. 

When i proceed to click on cancel it then returns me :



Returned Error after failing to attempt to log in to azure The authorization type you provided is not supported. Only Basic and OAuth are supported
bing

Comment: For authentification... use empty login and your primary account key as password.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid is there a way to do site specific query like I want to obtain search results just from Linkedin?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Azure DataMarket and its APIs has been closed so you will need to switch to a new API like Google or DuckDuckGo

[Microsoft Closing Azure DataMarket](https://adtmag.com/articles/2016/11/18/azure-datamarket-shutdown.aspx)

// Old Answer

The way the new Bing API works is different, but you can use it without logging in, by base64 encoding your AppId and then setting it as the "Basic" authorization in the headers. I got the idea from [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311286/what-are-the-ajax-authorization-headers-for-a-bing-api-request/27315449#27315449). The trick is that you need to add a colon at the beginning of your AppId before base64 encoding it.

Here is a working example I made that searches Bing and returns a random image from the results. If you want to make it work, just add your own AppId:

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
  //Declare variables
  var $searchButton = $('#searchButton');
  //add a colon to the beginning of your AppId string
  var appId = ':TZYNotARealAppId';

  //Function to get images
  function getImage() {
    //base64 encode the AppId
    var azureKey = btoa(appId);
    //get the value from the search box
    var $searchQuery = $('#searchBox').val();
    //Create the search string
    var myUrl = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=%27image%27&$top=50&$format=json&Query=%27' + $searchQuery + '%27';
    //Make post request to bing
    $.ajax({
      method: 'post',
      url: myUrl,
      //Set headers to authorize search with Bing
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + azureKey
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //Insert random image in dom
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        var imgLink = '<img width="500px" src="' + data.d.results[0].Image[randomIndex].MediaUrl + '" />';
        $('#output').html(imgLink);
      },
      failure: function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
  };
  //Trigger function when button is clicked
  $searchButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getImage();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Image search widget</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="test search widget" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <form>
      <input id="searchBox" type="text" type="submit" name="searchBox" required/>
      <button id="searchButton" type="submit">Get Image</button>
    </form>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/search.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This method still works. I've created a fiddle just in case someone wants to experiment. https://jsfiddle.net/skd/28toz2n2/