# What are the Ajax authorization headers for a Bing API request?

Tags: http, azure, bing-api

I'm sending an ajax request to the Bing Search API. The URL I am using for the request works when I put it in the browser. With ajax I get a 401 error `"The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported"`

therefore my header is wrong. It works in the browser because I manually type in my azure account key.

```
<script>
        $scope.bingsearch = function() {

            var azurekey = '....vjrQiHPp4ct1meqroX2pzQZhPvE';
            var keywords = $scope.inputvalue;
            var myurl = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?
                   Sources=%27web%27&$format=json&Query=%27'+ keywords + '%27';

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: myurl,
                headers:{
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + azurekey  
                }
            }).success(function(data){
                var searchresults = angular.fromJson(+data);
                $scope.searchresult = searchresults;
            })
        };
</script>
```

The URL `https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources=%27web%27&$format=json&Query=%27van%20gogh%27` works in the browser.

How do I set my header so that it will accept my account key?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to Base64 encode my Azure key in the headers, *prefixed by a colon.* I went to [this website](https://www.base64encode.org/)
and pasted a colon ":" plus my Azure account key and base64'd it.

So my key `OQA/cs` becomes `:OQA/cs` then base64'd into `Ok9RQS9jcw==` and the final header looks like

```
                `headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic Ok9RQS9jcw=='
                 }`
```

and Bing returns the json I want. Do not forget to include the colon as the *first character* of your account key *before you encode it* so that you Base64 encode it as *part of your key*.