# Bing Image Search API Authorise within Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, bing-api

I've been putting together a Google Sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pp9QyrF-aaM6cT9mOs9BWODwbSc2ZHXAovCU2fxQ6Uc/edit?usp=sharing) 
that automatically uses the Google Custom Search API (I set up a free account to test) to pull in images to the table from a feed provided by the Google Custom Search API.

The problem is that Google's Custom Search API service seems to be totally unreliable and inconsistent, with the generated search URL's (results in column S of the linked spreadsheet) sometimes returning a useable result (and picture), sometimes returning an empty feed (for no obvious reason) or sometimes giving me a "This site can’t be reached" "ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE" error which is equally inexplicable since the URLs are all formed by the same code.

So I've had a look at the Microsoft  Bing Image Search API to see if their results were more reliable and found that I can also use a URL to return an XML feed of results (which I could then parse within Google Sheets to get the image links (i hope!).

The problem is that with the awful Google Custom Search API, I could at least put the authentication information in the URL itself so Google Sheets just followed the link and got the data from the search result. With Bing, which produces much more reliable results, it asks for authentication via a browser dialog and states that "Only Basic and OAuth are supported".

Now I've looked into how I could get Google Sheets to authenticate the URL queries but haven't had much luck figuring it out.

Also saw that you can apparently authenticate using the Basic method but the account key needs to be converted to Base64 and a colon added in front of it but this then needs to be set in the (http?) headers: [How do i return JSON results from BING Search Engine API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732530/how-do-i-return-json-results-from-bing-search-engine-api).

Can headers be set via a script in Google Sheets and/or can the Bing Search API urls be authorised from within Google Sheets in some way?

Otherwise is there anything obvious as to what I'm doing wrong with the Google Search URL's that return such broken and inconsistent results?

I'd prefer to get the Bing Search URL's authorised within Google Sheets ideally.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck with this? i am trying to do the same thing and authenticate using Bing Search API inside Google Sheets